# How to read Item's media field properties using SPE

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have an item where we have a "Article Thumbnail" field(Media type) and an image is inserted from Media Library.

Now I need to check for **Alt** text in Item's media properties. I am trying with below script and finding an odd behavior. When I browse for Item's field, I see an *empty alt*. But when I do selection for that field, it is going to its media library item and fetching me the alt. So, how to get correct Item's Image alt ?

[image]

To be more clear, see the highlighted part (**Alternate Text** and **Default Alternate Text**)
[image]

Comment: Post your code as snippets instead of screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to either cast the field to the proper field type or use the `PSFields` collection to access it for you.

Read more [here](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items#get-item-properties-with-field-type).

**Example:** The following gets the home item of a site, accesses the HeroImage field and expands the Alt text.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{961563FC-3445-4558-BF3A-06DF06BA6298}"
$item.PSFields.HeroImage.Alt
```

[image: Example]

### Update

Based on your revised requirements here is what I've learned.

When accessing the **Alt** field on the `ImageField` type the text is first extracted from the xml in the field followed by a fallback to the text on the media item. Doesn't appear that the **Alt** property provides a way to *know* whether or not it's the default value.

You could try something like the following:

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{961563FC-3445-4558-BF3A-06DF06BA6298}"
$detectedValue = $item.PSFields.HeroImage.Alt
$defaultValue = $item.PSFields.HeroImage.MediaItem["Alt"]

if($defaultValue -ne $detectedValue) {
    Write-Host "This has been overridden"
} else {
    Write-Host "This is the default value"
}

$rawValue = $item.PSFields.HeroImage.GetAttribute("alt")
if($detectedValue -ne $rawValue) {
    Write-Host "It's showing the default value"
}
```

[image: Example]

"ABC" is stored in `$rawValue` and `$detectedValue`. If I cleared it out `$detectedValue` would match `$defaultValue` and `$rawValue` would be blank.

Comment: Thank you @Michael

I have elaborated my question with another Image. In the Image, I need "Alternate Text" value and not "Default Alternate Text". The .PSFields.Alt is returning "Default Alternate Text" if Alternate Text is empty.

Comment: OH yeah, interesting dilemma. I updated my answer to include a solution for that.

Comment: Thank you! GetAttribute does all the trick here.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your item media field into `ImageField` in `PowerShell` and it will give you all the properties of this field. Here is the example code.

```
# Get the item using the ID
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}"

# Pass your field name. In the example below it is Image and cast into the ImageField
$imageField = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField]$item.Fields["Image"]
```

You will get all the properties like this.

[image]

If your field doesn't have the `alt` value set then you could go to the Image Item using the `mediaid` and get the value from there. Here is the example code.

```
# Get the actual Sitecore Image item by passing the mediaID (see your raw value of the image field)
$imageItem = Get-Item -Path master: -ID $imageField.mediaID

# Get the Alt value from the Image Item
$altValue = $imageItem.Fields["Alt"].Value
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you @Sumit. Please see my comment above replied for Michael West. 

My requirement is to get Alt value in item's media field and NOT Media's Alt from source.

Comment: I got your requirement after updating your Question. So it is good to get the Raw Value and get the attribute from there.

Comment: Use `$imageField.GetAttribute("alt")` to get the attribute.

Comment: Thank you! GetAttribute does all the trick here.